# Unable to upload files with any browser on Ubuntu 14.04, why?

Tags: 14.04, networking, kernel, upload

please, I need your help. I have a weird problem. I am unable to upload 
files to gmail, gdrive, facebook nor other website with Ubuntu 14.04

I am able to ping google, watch youtube videos and download files
perfectly. But I cannot upload files. The upload process seems to
start correctly.

[image: File upload starts without problems]

But all my files stops at 10 to 15% (pay attention to CPU graph)

[image: File stops at 10 to 15%]

after that, the browser process goes to 50% and my upload stops and after
some minutes is restarted and stop again at 10% :S

[image: browser process goes to 50%]

I tried Firefox, Opera, Chrome.
Also I installed other ubuntu flavors (ubuntu 14.10, kubuntu 14.04, 
xubuntu 14.04), other distros (Mint 17, openSUSE 13.2) but 
the problem persist.

Interface Eth0 and wireless present the same problem.

My router is a WIMAX router DV235.

(I think there is a kernel problem, maybe a new way to handle 
the connections but I am not a pro. I
tried kernel 3.16, 3.13, 3.11 also but they have the same problem)

With Ubuntu 12.04 and Debian 7.7 (kernel 3.2) uploads works perfectly.
Do you have any ideas?
(If you need additional info please tell me to post it)

Comment: I already have installed ubuntu-restricted-extras. I enabled/disabled the browser addons, but the problem persists :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that there is a kernel issue because I did [upload tests](http://testmy.net/upload)
with different kernel versions from [kernel.ubuntu.com](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/) on a
fresh ubuntu 14.04 installation.

First I tested [v3.14.26](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.14.26-utopic/) but uploads do not work.

After that, I tested [v3.10.62](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.10.62-saucy/) and everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether addon is enabled in browser and use the below command,

sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras

Hope this helps.