# Unable to upload any file from any browser Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, upload

I'm new to Ubuntu therefore I don't know if this issue is already resolved or not. I'm unable to upload any file in any browser. When I did speed test with okla downloading is 10 Mbps but uploading is not working.

I did some research and found this: [Unable to upload files with any browser on Ubuntu 14.04, why?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/558297/unable-to-upload-files-with-any-browser-on-ubuntu-14-04-why)

Therefore I need to change my kernel. Is it?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: No router or isp problem, I am using wifi. For other devices it's running very well. Even for Ubuntu youtube streaming and downloading is very fast. Thanks

Comment: I tried testing in a VM if Firefox would have this problem if /tmp was missing or had invalid permissions but it didn't seem to cause any problems.

Comment: Therefore I need to update permission in /tmp, is that?

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce the issue so I don't think /tmp is the problem. I am simply putting that information here for anyone else wondering if that was the problem.

Comment: What you can try doing is closing Firefox, opening your home directory, show hidden files and rename your `.mozilla` directory to something else like `not.mozilla` then launch Firefox and see if the issue persists. Assuming it still happens you can restore your original Firefox settings by renaming the `not.mozilla` folder back to `.mozilla`

Comment: It's appearing in all browser therefore I need to do it for all manually?

Comment: You might find https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting.html.en useful.

Comment: I highly recommend that you visit [this  page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) and then [edit] your question to include more information. Thank you for helping us help you!